# Different abbreviation options for the same acronym in glossary

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I want to be able to have an acronym in glossary, which when referred to with `\gls{}` would appear in the main text in a standard form, unless specified otherwise.

I.e. i have the following acronyms:

```
\newacronym{a1}{A1}{Apples 1}
\newacronym{a2}{A2}{Apples 2}
```

I am writing about two types of apples, **A1** and **A2**. But i am mostly interested in **A1**, so i just want them to be abbreviated as **A** from now on. So i guess i'm looking whether something like the following exists:

```
\newacronym{a1}{A}{A1}{Apples 1}
\gls{a1}
```

(abbreviation appears as **A**)

```
\gls{a1}[version2]
```

(abbreviation appears as **A1**).

Are there any standard options in glossary for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods that I can think of.

### 1. Just the base `glossaries` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{a}{A}{Apples}
\newacronym[parent=a]{a1}{A1}{Apples 1}
\newacronym[parent=a]{a2}{A2}{Apples 2}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{a1}, \gls{a2}, \gls{a}.

Next use: \gls{a1}, \gls{a2}, \gls{a}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This establishes a hierarchical set of abbreviations:

[image: image of document]

The `\gls{a}` reference links to the parent entry in the list.

### 2. The [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{a1}{A1}{Apples 1}
\newacronym{a2}{A2}{Apples 2}

\newglossaryentry{a}{name={A},description={Apples},alias={a1}}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{a1}, \gls{a2}, \gls{a}.

Next use: \gls{a1}, \gls{a2}, \gls{a}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This uses the `alias` key that makes the hyperlink for `\gls{a}` go to the target for `a1`. The aliased entry is listed in the glossary with a cross-reference:

[image: image of document]

The first use of `\gls{a}` doesn't show the full form as it's not an abbreviation. It can be an abbreviation if you prefer:

```
\newacronym[alias=a1]{a}{A}{Apples}
```

If you don't want the aliased term to appear at all in the list, you can create an ignored glossary and assign it to that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{a1}{A1}{Apples 1}
\newacronym{a2}{A2}{Apples 2}

\newignoredglossary*{ignored}
\newglossaryentry{a}{name={A},description={Apples},alias={a1},type=ignored}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{a1}, \gls{a2}, \gls{a}.

Next use: \gls{a1}, \gls{a2}, \gls{a}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The `\gls{a}` reference links to the main glossary even though `a` is in an ignored glossary that doesn't show up with `\printglossaries`.

[image: image of document]

### 3. The [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package and [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls).

This assigns a post-link hook for the aliased entry (which now has the category label `aliased`) so that on first use it will show both terms.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@acronym{a1,
  short={A1},
  long={Apples 1}
}
@acronym{a2,
  short={A2},
  long={Apples 2}
}
@index{a,
  name={A},
  alias={a1},
  seealso={a1,a2},
  category={aliased}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=tree,record]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={\jobname}% entries in \jobname.bib
]

\glsdefpostlink{aliased}{%
 \glsxtrifwasfirstuse
 {%
   \glsxtrifhasfield{seealso}{\glslabel}%
   {%
     \let\DTLlistformatitem\glsxtrlong
     \space(\DTLformatlist{\glscurrentfieldvalue})%
   }%
   {}%
 }%
 {}%
}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{a1}, \gls{a2}, \gls{a}.

Next use: \gls{a1}, \gls{a2}, \gls{a}.

\renewcommand{\printunsrtglossaryentryprocesshook}[1]{%
  \glsxtrifhasfield*{alias}{#1}{\printunsrtglossaryskipentry}{}%
}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

Instead of creating an ignored glossary, I've redefined the hook used by `\printunsrtglossary` to skip any entry that has the `alias` field set.

[image: image of document]

The command `\glsdefpostlink` was new to `glossaries-extra` v1.31. If you have an older version you can change:

```
\glsdefpostlink{aliased}{%
```

to:

```
\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkaliased}{%
```

Here's a minor variation that includes a description for the aliased entry:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@acronym{a1,
  short={A1},
  long={Apples 1}
}
@acronym{a2,
  short={A2},
  long={Apples 2}
}
@entry{a,
  name={A},
  description={Apples},
  alias={a1},
  seealso={a1,a2},
  category={aliased}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=tree,record]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={\jobname}% entries in \jobname.bib
]

\glsdefpostlink{aliased}{%
 \glsxtrifwasfirstuse
 {%
   \space(\glsentrydesc{\glslabel}%
     \glsxtrifhasfield{seealso}{\glslabel}%
     {%
       \let\DTLlistformatitem\glsxtrlong
       :\space\DTLformatlist{\glscurrentfieldvalue}%
     }%
     {}%
   )%
 }%
 {}%
}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{a1}, \gls{a2}, \gls{a}.

Next use: \gls{a1}, \gls{a2}, \gls{a}.

\renewcommand{\printunsrtglossaryentryprocesshook}[1]{%
  \glsxtrifhasfield*{alias}{#1}{\printunsrtglossaryskipentry}{}%
}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Nicola!
I don't want *A* to appear in the Glossary and your option 2 seemed the easiest one to implement, but your code does not seem to work for me:

`! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

l.13 \newignoredglossary*{i
                           gnored}

! Package xkeyval Error: `alias' undefined in families `glossentry'.
l.14 ...cription={Apples},alias={a1},type=ignored}

`

Comment: @InternazionalIV The `alias` key was added to `glossaries-extra` version 1.12 (2017-02-03) so I suspect your version is too old.

Comment: Right you are! Thanks!! Ready to submit my dissertation about the apples now..

Comment: @InternazionalIV Good luck with it :-)